# cakephp 3.* doesn't recognize new database column

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

CakePHP Version: 3.2.7
I create a table users and I use cakephp to bake All users. I get all working with bake. Then I add a new column to the database and set all code necessary to let cakephp now about the new column.

I expect that cakephp recognize the new database column and all will work normally.

I try to use the column that already was in the table when I bake all users an all work perfectly except the new column that I add after the bake.

Comment: change debug to false, execute a page, then change back to true. as per @voycey it sounds like cache

Answer (score 2):

CakePHP stores the database schema in the cache to prevent having to fetch it from the database each time a call is made, if you have debug=true in your app.php the caches are cleared every 10 seconds, if you want to keep this as it currently is you can clear the cache manually by using the ORM Cache shell from the command line:

```
# Clear all metadata
bin/cake orm_cache clear

# Clear a single table
bin/cake orm_cache clear users
```

This is discussed in the following documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/orm-cache.html